# DJI Mini 3 Pro EXIF azimuth is ~11 degrees west of true north

Tags: dji, sensor, camera

I have a Mini 3 Pro and a number of Python scripts that will map image locations from drone images.  This all happens using the on-board GNSS unit and the values written to the the image EXIF data.

On this new Mini 3 Pro I  noticed that the GNSS azimuth value is consistently about 11 degrees(or so) west of the azimuth of the front of the drone.  I have confirmed this by snapping images of a N/S road but the EXIF angle of the images shows the 11 degree west shift in the camera angle. the drone camera points straight up the N/S running road.   This 11 degrees messes with the outputs from my scripts and I want to figure out the cause and correct it.

I have, before my test flight mentioned above, completed a compass calibration and an IMU calibration but I still experience this issue.

Do all Mini 3 Pros have an 11 degree (or so) shift, do I have a lemon that need to be returned to DJI, or is there something I am missing in the settings?

FYI the magnetic declination for my area is about 17 degrees east of true north so the issue is not magnetic declination.  Also, I have experienced this across my local region an there is no magnetic anomoly to explain the shift in the EXIF data.

Any input is appreciated.